# Property contentItem in Qml

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

The following Qml code gives the following output (expected):

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

Window {
    height: 200
    width: 200
    visible: true

    Button {
        id: root
        text: "Text"
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Item {
            anchors.fill: parent
            Text {
                text: "Item.Text"
                color: "red"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The following code (using **contentItem**) produces a different output:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

Window {
    height: 200
    width: 200
    visible: true

    Button {
        id: root
        text: "Text"
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        contentItem: Item {
            anchors.fill: parent
            Text {
                text: "Item.Text"
                color: "red"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html#contentItem-prop) is not very clear, at least for me. The question is what does the property **contentItem** do? When it should be used?

Comment: the contentItem is a way to customize a control, in your first code you are adding a child item to the button, and in the second customizing the same button, so both implementations have different objectives so both implementations are correct, so you must use one or the other according to what you want, so what output do you want?

Comment: @eyllanesc: how did you conclude that contentItem is used to customize a Qml object? Reading the Qt documentation I couldn't conclude that. 
Does contentItem override the caption only?

Comment: Qt Quick Controls II allows you to customize using that element, check the docs: see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html

Comment: no, actually you should use the control text (button) inside the contentitem, consider that it has the same task as the delegates in the views, for example you can make the button is square, circle, etc., that has an image as a background , etc., that has a color with respect to a state, etc. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html#contentItem-prop

Comment: @eyllanesc: I really don't understand a single word of whatever you are saying. I visited all the links you have shared. Anyway, thanks for the comments.

Comment: In summary Qt Quick Controls II is an improved version of the old items written in C ++ and exposed to QML, and for the customization of the item the contentitem is used, for example let's say you want a button that is round in the normal state and when press square, how would you do it, since overwriting the contentitem, in the link that I have provided, several examples are shown using the button.

Comment: Do not ask for reasons for the downvote, it is currently considered noise, read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin. the downvotes and upvotes are anonymous, so it's not impolite not to point it out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer: The `contentItem` is meant for customizing the control and replaces the existing implementation of the visual foreground element by your text.

---

Long answer:

A Quick `Item` has a so called "default property" - the [`data`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-item.html#data-prop) property. By definition, if you add an item as child of another item, it is instead assigned to the default property. Which means the following example:

```
Item {
    Text { text: "test1"} 
}
```

Is actually identical to:

```
Item {
    data: [
        Text { text: "test2"}
    ]
}
```

If you know look at your example, in the first variant, you simply append a child item to the root button. Since no further information is given, it is placed at the coordinates `(0,0)` within it's parent.

The `contentItem` property however is defined in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html#contentItem-prop) as follows:

> This property holds the visual content item.

In case of a `Button` it is an internally used `Label` to display the `text` property of the button. It exists to modify the appereance of the button.

In your second example, you "customize" the button by replacing the internal label with your custom `Text` - but without any code to properly position or fill the item. The correct way to declare a content item can be found in the [customization guide](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-button):

```
Button {
    id: control
    text: qsTr("Button")

    contentItem: Text {
        text: control.text
        font: control.font
        opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
        color: control.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        elide: Text.ElideRight
    }

    // ...
}
```

You could either define it as part of a custom style, or create a `MyButton.qml` where do exactly this and can then use `MyButton` in other QML files, giving you a custom styled button whilest keeping the API intact (like beeing able to set the text via the `text` property etc.)

I hope this was sufficient enough to help you understand how it works.

Comment: Somebody speaks logic! Thank you @Felix!
I get it now, contentItem is specific to every Qml component. I did read the links you provided couple of times but didn't really understand it the way you explained it! 

To add to your answer, the source code says it all. The Buttom.qml shows the customization for the Button text and background. See this: https://github.com/qt/qtquickcontrols2/blob/d56c193eb4ceb640611d66f22e1f26aae91cd7d1/src/imports/controls/Button.qml#L61

Comment: Please note that the link you are referring to is the implementation of the "Default" design. check the subfolders in that directory for the button implementations for other styles, like Material, Universal, etc.